# Old Codeigniter project do not logging.( I changed the Encrypt library file)

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, encryption, mcrypt

My Old codeigniter project is not logging in.. First it showed the error as mcrypt error after that I changed the ecrypt library file.. but now it is not showing any errors and not logging... 
Note:- project developed in php 5....

```
 public function login()
    {
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $userEmail    = $this->input->post('login_email');
        $userPassword = $this->input->post('login_password');


        $userInfo = $this->user_model->getPasswordByUsername($userEmail); 
        if($userInfo)
        { //echo $userPassword.'#'.$this->encrypt->decode($userInfo['password'],ENCRYPT_STRING).'##'.$this->encrypt->encode($this->input->post('login_password'), ENCRYPT_STRING);exit;
            if($userPassword==$this->encrypt->decode($userInfo['password'],ENCRYPT_STRING))
            {
               $user_data = array(
                   'userid'    =>$userInfo['id'],
                   'user_name' =>$userInfo['name'],
                   'user_email'=>$userInfo['email'],
                   'level'=>$userInfo['level']
               );

               if ($userEmail==('user@ajhd.com')) {
                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
               redirect('http://dummy.hrmsonline.net/index.php/dashboard');

               } else {
                   $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
               redirect('/dashboard');
               }


            }else
            { 
                $this->session->set_flashdata('invalid','true');
                redirect('auth');
            }           
        }else
        { 
            $this->session->set_flashdata('invalid','true');    
            redirect('auth');
        }


    }
```

Comment: Did u check that your request is reaching the method or not??

Comment: Perhaps it is doing its job and perhaps it is not but without seeing the upstream and downstream of the code it is hard to tell. Have you incorporated print or print_r commands at appropriate place to see if it is working? Please include more details to help you.

Comment: @FazlanAhamed yes bro I checked it reaching my method. I think the main problem is in encryption

Comment: Brother, encode the $userEmail and compare with user record's password because some of the hash algorithm cannot be decoded